# Trailing zeros of Product of first N factorials

Tags: algorithm, math

I am trying to solve this coding question.

For a positive integer n, its factorial is defined as the product of all integers from 1 to n, denoted as n!. Now n double factorial is the product of 1 factorial, 2 factorial, ..., up to n factorial: 1! · 2! · 3! · ... · n!. Given n(1 ≤ n ≤ 10^18), find the number of trailing zeros of a decimal representation of n double factorial.

I tried to solve it by dividing it by 5 from 1 to n, but the n was too big to solve it in time.
( time limit is 1s )

```python
cnt = 0
for i in (1,n+1):
    while i >= 5:
        cnt += i//5
        i //= 5
```

So, I tried other way like stirling approximation and any other way. But I couldn't solve this problem.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hint: print the first few (100-200) answers, and see what they look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take an example: n = 15.

The number of 5s can be counted as :

5/5 = 1, 6/5 = 1, 7/5 = 1, 8/5 = 1, 9/5 = 1, and

10/5 = 2, 11/5 = 2, 12/5 = 2, 13/5 = 2, 14/5 = 2,

now for 15 : 15/5 = 3

You can see that there are groups before 15. The first group (5-9) contributed 5 5s,
the second group contributed 5x2 = 10 5s.

In general the number of 5s contributed by each group is `5 * group`

15 falls in the third group but the number of 5s contributed is counted as 3 which is

its `position_in_the_group * group` = 1*3 = 3

Therefore

*total number of 5s for n =
(total number of 5s contributed by all its previous groups) +
(number of 5s contributed by itself in its own group and its members in the group before it)*

You could use `n*(n+1)/2` (formula for sum of first n numbers) to calculate sum of number of groups.

With that the formula for counting 5s will be:

```
5*((group-1)*(group-1+1)/2) + pos*group

= 5*(group*(group-1)/2) + pos*group
```

This is just for `5`

Now you need to repeat the same process for `25, 75, 125` etc. until your group is < 1.

The python code will be:

```
 def get_trailing_zeros_double_factorial(n):
   res = 0
   group = n//5
   m = 5
   pos = n%m + 1
   n0 = n
   while group >= 1:
     res += m*(group*(group-1)//2) + pos*group
     n = n//5
     group = n//5
     m = m*5
     pos = (n0 % m) + 1
   return res
```

Output:

```
print(get_trailing_zeros_double_factorial(2))
print(get_trailing_zeros_double_factorial(5))
print(get_trailing_zeros_double_factorial(8))
print(get_trailing_zeros_double_factorial(11))
print(get_trailing_zeros_double_factorial(25))
print(get_trailing_zeros_double_factorial(50))
print(get_trailing_zeros_double_factorial(3443134134))
print(get_trailing_zeros_double_factorial(10 ** 18))

0
1
4
9
56
262
1481896560464509130
124999999999999987370803833007812495
```

Comment: when n is 50 output must be 262. but this code's output is 247.

Comment: I solved it.
' res += int(p*5*(group*(group-1)/2)) + pos*group ' has to be change to ' res += int((5**p)*(group*(group-1)/2)) + pos*group '

Comment: Suggest `group*(group-1)//2` instead of `group*(group-1)/2`, so that you're using integer arithmetic throughout. (`group*(group-1)/2` gives the wrong answer for e.g., `group = 200000002` and many other values of similar or larger magnitude)

Comment: @SEONGILKIM you are right it should be power of 5 in the first part just like with the other part, modified the code.

Comment: @MarkDickinson yes agreed. I changed the code. Thanks.